# How to apply a custom function to groups in a dask dataframe, using multiple columns as function input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, dask

I have a very large dataframe that I'm handling with **dask**. 
The dataframe looks by and large like this:

```
Col_1    Col_2   Bool_1   Bool_2
A        1       True     False
B        1       True     True
C        1       False    False
D        1       True     False
A        2       False    True
B        2       False    False
C        2       True     False
D        2       True     True
```

But it has millions of rows.

What I'm trying to do at this point of the code is to calculate a **Jaccard distance** between `Bool_1` and `Bool_2` for each group formed in `Col_2`. This, because the aim of this program is to produce *one line for each group* that is present in `Col_2` (each line has several statistics, I'm reporting only the relevant columns).

To do so, I first group the dataframe by `Col_2` using `df.groupby("Col_2")`, but then I don't know how to proceed. Every attempt I tried so far has thrown an error.

**1**: I tried to define a function `compute_jacc_dist()` and to pass it via `apply(compute_jacc_dist, axis=1)` to the groups, but it has issues with the args and kwargs (the axis especially, see https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1572 , which I couldn't solve yet).

**2**: I tried to use `from dask_distance import jaccard` and use it to compute the J distance between `Bool_1` and `Bool_2` but it produces weird results (each group returns J=1 even if there is NO intersection).

**3**: I tried to `compute()` the dataframe and to iterate over the groups using:

```
for name, group in df.groupby("Col_2"):
   jacc = dask_distance.jaccard(group["Bool_1"], group["Bool_2"])
```

But this one is slow as hell because it triggers a computation and then operates over such a huge dataframe group by group (i.e. I don't want to use it). For reference, a script with this function is running since two days, while I estimate that any of the solutions #1 and #2 I have tried, if properly set, would return results in 1-2 hours.

Any suggestion on how I could handle this issue? My ideal solution would be to use `df.groupby("Col_1").apply(compute_jacc_dist)` in a proper way. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After many hours of trying, here's how I did it. If you're reading this, you may wanna read this ([How to apply euclidean distance function to a groupby object in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064346/how-to-apply-euclidean-distance-function-to-a-groupby-object-in-pandas-dataframe)) and this ([Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)).

```
def my_function(x):

    d = {}
    v1 = np.array(x["Bool_1"])
    v2 = np.array(x["Bool_2"])
    intersection = np.logical_and(v1, v2).sum()
    union = np.logical_or(v1, v2).sum()
    d["Jaccard"] = float(intersection) / float(union)
    return pd.Series(d, index=["Jaccard"])

df = df.groupby("Col_2").apply(my_function, meta={"Jaccard":"float16"}).compute()
```

**Explanation**

I create a function that computes the Jaccard distance between the two columns of my dataframe. Within the function, I create a dictionary (`d`) which will contain the results of my computations.

A perk of having a dictionary is that I can add as many computations as I want, although here there is only one.

The function then returns a `pd.Series` containing the dictionary.

The function is applied to the dataframe groups, which are based on `Col_2`. `meta` data types are specified within `apply()`, and the whole thing has `compute()` at the end, since it's a dask dataframe and a computation must be triggered to get the result.

The `apply()` should have as many `meta` as there are output columns.