# Apply euclidean distance function with null values - Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, euclidean-distance

I've got this function from a separate question: [How to apply euclidean distance function to a groupby object in pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064346/how-to-apply-euclidean-distance-function-to-a-groupby-object-in-pandas-dataframe). The following function measures the distance between objects grouped by `time` and `ids`. The issue I'm having is when there isn't enough coordinates. There's a run time error

```
RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.(np.array(list(zip(x['x'], x['y']))))
```

I'm hoping to pass 0 when this occurs.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np

time = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
x = [216, 218, 217, 280, 290, 130, 132]
y = [13, 12, 12, 110, 109, 3, 56]
car = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 5]
ids = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'x': x, 'y': y, 'car': car, 'ids': ids})

df = (df.groupby(['time','ids'])
        .apply(lambda x: spatial.distance.pdist
        (np.array(list(zip(x['x'], x['y']))))
        .mean())
        .reset_index()
        )
```

Intended Output:

```
   time ids           0
0     0   a   78.042816
1     0   b           0
2     1   a           0
3     1   b  191.927069
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a condition in the lambda function is one trick:

```py
(df.groupby(['time','ids'])
   .apply(lambda x: spatial.distance.pdist
       (np.array(list(zip(x['x'], x['y'])))).mean() if len(x)>1 else 0)
   .reset_index()
)

   time ids           0
0     0   a   78.042816
1     0   b    0.000000
2     1   a    0.000000
3     1   b  191.927069
```

Comment: Cheers @FBruzzesi